Call to undefined function wp_get_wp_version()
Background: Several years ago I developed a simple WordPress site for my local government that they took over in terms of managing/updating.  This summer a local resident contacted me stating the site wasn't loading, and I reached out to the current admin user to see if I could assist.  When attempting to access the site's login (or any other resource), we see the message "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."
The current admin has assured me they've searched their mailbox and have no emails from WordPress with a link to recovery mode logins.  I've since changed the admin user's email to mine via MySQL, but haven't received any emails from WP regarding the site.  The host, Network Solutions, told me they cannot restore a backup as they're only retained for 30 days, and I was brought in about 5 months after the site went down in February.
So far, I've tried the basics like:

Renaming the plugins folder and active theme folder via SFTP, without any impact.
The WP version appears to have been upgraded around the time this
issue occurred.  Either from 6.3.1 to 6.6.2, or unsuccessfully from
6.6.2 to 6.7.1.  The current WP version is reported 6.6.3.  I do not know the PHP version and the host is unable to provide that info.  I
will try to upload a PHP file to determine it later this evening.
I can access the MySQL database where I also disabled all plugins,
but still no joy
I also manually replaced WP 6.6.3 with the original 6.3.1, but this
still did nothing.

I updated the wp_config.php file to enable debugging, and see the following message in the output, though I'm unsure how to resolve it.  Has anyone ever seen this?

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_get_wp_version() in /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-includes/blocks/index.php:30
Stack trace:
#0 /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): register_core_block_style_handles()
#1 /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#3 /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-settings.php(700): do_action()
#4 /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-config.php(81): require_once('/data/user/2018...')
#5 /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/data/user/2018...')
#6 /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-blog-header.ph in /data/user/2018/295/5738/wordpress/.5f11b27f131494a1c014fcced2f13165/wp-includes/blocks/index.php on line 30

UPDATE
@Dmitry Leiko's suggestion to rollback to 6.2.6 worked in part to get the site's pages loading, partially.  I downloaded the WP 6.2.6 zip and uploaded it via FTP, excluding the content directory.  Once that was done I was getting the below message trying to login:

Forbidden You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/upgrade.php on
this server.

Renaming hte site's .htaccess file to .htaccess_old got back to the login page, but I was being prompted to update the MySQL database since the version value in the version.php file was wrong.  So I did have to login to MySQL and execute SELECT option_value FROM dbname.wp_options WHERE option_name = 'db_version'  to determine the correct MySQL value, which I added to the wp-includes/version.php file, and now I'm back in.
Thank you to everyone who tried to help, I very much appreciate it!

You can try to create custom function in your yourTheme/function.php:
if (!function_exists('wp_get_wp_version')) {
    function wp_get_wp_version() {
        static $wp_version;

        if (!isset($wp_version)){
            require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/version.php';
        }

        return $wp_version;
    }
}


Also you can try rollback your wordpress to 6.2.6


Thank you.  Unfortunately this did not work for me

@B4THC4T - Please edit your question and update it - Please explain why this solution didn't work for you - Are you receiving any errors?

@DarkBee Including this change has no effect.  Same error as listed in question.  Same message in debug.log.

If you get the same error with this snippet, then the code never ran to start with

Also you can try rollback your wordpress to 6.2.6

@DarkBee I can assure you I added the PHP block to the active theme's functions.php file, just before it's functions began and cleared the debug.log.  The change had no effect.  My apologies, I'm not sure if that's what you meant

@DmitryLeiko Thank you!  This worked!  At least in part.  Some of the content isn't working, but I can login.  I did have to update the wp-incudes/version.php file to reflect the WP version, and obtain the MySQL version from the MySQL database, but I'm back up.  Thank you!

@B4THC4T I can assure you the code never ran, look at what the posted snippet does:  If the function does not exists, then create it. How could you get the same error?

@DarkBee I rcan assure you it was added as requested.  And yes, I read the code, I write PHP.  I continued to get the same error due to the WP version issue, which was causing a complete load failure.  Possibly theme corruption as well as I had to reupload it after rolling back WP.. That's why adding the function back in accomplished nothing.  Thanks anyway!


<?php
    add_action('init', function () {
        global $wp_version;
        echo $wp_version;
    });
    ?>


Thanks for the reply.  To what .php file am I adding this?

function.php
here insert a code

Thanks..  I added it to wp-includes/functions.php, but no effect.  Still getting the same error.

go to
'wp-includes/version.php'
see line no 19
this variable "$wp_version"
check here wordpress version

$wp_version = '6.6.2'; Will update question

Yes this wordpress version and now check php version in cpnael
if version is 7.4 then upgrade php vesion 7.4 to 8.1

Unfortunately this host doesn't use cPanel.  I do not have the ability to change the PHP version.  I can only change the WP version

Please remove call this function 'wp_get_wp_version'
then check

I tried removing it, and changing it to = '6.6.2' , but no effect.  Here's where it's called: function register_core_block_style_handles() {
$wp_version = wp_get_wp_version();

Please explain how this solves the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

only one solution php version upgrade 7.4 to 8.2

@Maulikpatel: This it literally not possible.  I know with many hosts you can do this, but Network Solutions does not allow users on it's WP Hosting to change the PHP version.  I've spoken to their support staff about this several times, including today.  It's simply not possible.

@Maulikpatel Also, WordPress 6.6.2 only requires PHP 7.2.  Why is an upgrade to 8.2 necessary?

https://i.sstatic.net/EaY8EwZP.png

Perhaps you misunderstood.   The version of WP we're running, 6.6.2, does not require a PHP version greater than 7.2.  Your image confirms this by showing beta support for 8.2 was introducted early in WP v6.  But this doesn't change the fact that 6.,6.2 only requires PHP 7.2.  Are you reading that differently?
